# Кодировка русских символов в ответе на HTTP запрос python3

Tags: python-3.x

Я делаю запрос с помощью HTTPSConnection и в ответе вместо русских символов получаю чары.

Делаю запрос и паршу его таким образом

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("***.ru")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=json;')

dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format('multipart/form-data'))
dataList.append('')

dataList.append("someJSON")
dataList.append('--'+boundary+'--')
dataList.append('')
body = '\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
  '****'
}
conn.request("POST", "/****", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Ответ получается типо такого

```
 {
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "someobject": [
            {
                "id": 319,
                "name": "\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f",
            }
     }
}
```

Как правильно обработать кирилицу для вывода и операций над ней (сравнения например s == "привет")?

Answer (score 1):

Просто разберите ответ через [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), получите в `name` текст `Акция`:

```
import json
import http.client
import mimetypes

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("***.ru")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append('--' + boundary)
dataList.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=json;')

dataList.append('Content-Type: {}'.format('multipart/form-data'))
dataList.append('')

dataList.append("someJSON")
dataList.append('--'+boundary+'--')
dataList.append('')
body = '\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
  '****'
}
conn.request("POST", "/****", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = json.loads(res.read())      # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть соглашение что юникодные символы использующие в URL перед отправкой/получением преобразуются по правилам процентного кодирования. Современные браузеры позаботятся о проблемах отображения  сделают их удобочитаемыми. Значит

```
"name": "\u0410\u043a\u0446\u0438\u044f",
```

лучше хранить в формате [процентного кодирования](https://html5css.ru/tags/ref_urlencode.php)

Но можно использовать и так, перед отправкой используй decode(). http.client должен понимать такие адреса

Comment: decode() использовать для body?

Comment: Я понял вопрос как вопрос про Юникод в URL. Если у тебя текст документа как набор символов. Ты просто  не применил к тексту кодировку (через decode() ) utf8  или cp1251 и т.д. Сделай так https://habr.com/ru/post/280238/